# Splitting file by prepared line numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file and I need to split it to smaller files by specific line index numbers.

I prepared indexes - lines where in line Header is:

```
listOfHeadersIndex = []

with open('Poland.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(csvfile):
        if '[Header]' in line:
            print(i)
            listOfHeadersIndex.append(i)
```

And:

```
listOFHeadersIndex is for example = 0,33,46,74.
```

Now I need to split it. The first file should contain 0-32 line, second 33-45, etc. I found only advice how to split by constant lines. How in a simple way can I accomplish it in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for.

```
with open('Poland.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    raw_data = csvfile.readlines()

file1=raw_data[0:33]
file2=raw_data[33:45]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listOfHeadersIndex = []
lines = []

with open('Poland.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(csvfile):
        lines.append(line)
        if '[Header]' in line:
            print(i)
            listOfHeadersIndex.append(i)

for i,a in enumerate(listOfHeadersIndex):
    first_index = a
    last_index = listOfHeadersIndex[i+1]-1
    str_ = ''
    for j,line in enumerate(lines):
       if j >= first_index and j <= last_index:
           if str_:
              str_+= '\n'.join(line)
           else:
              str_+= line
    f = open(f"file{i}.txt", "w")
    f.write(str)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly split the file.

**Ex:**

```
newFile = False
c = 1
with open('Poland.csv', 'r') as csvfile:       #Open SRC file
    for line in csvfile:              #Iterate Each line
        if '[Header]' in line:        #Check for header
            if newFile:               #Check if file is open
                newFile.close()       #Close file.
            newFile = open("{}.txt".format(c), "w")   #Create new file for write. 
            newFile.write(line)                       #Write Header. 
            c += 1
        else:
            newFile.write(line)                       #Write Content.
```